# Reflexive pronoun of someone

Tags: grammar

It is really hard to someone who has not any respect to *it's* own values to be respected by others.

What is the reflexive pronoun of someone?

Comment: The traditional pronoun is "his".  But you may be accused of sexism if you try that today.

Comment: Sometimes, one just has to work out for ***oneself*** that it's easier to refer to ***one** who has no respect*, rather than ***someone***.

Comment: [“Someone who undervalues themself could be described as self-deprecatory.”](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/46730/2085)

Answer (score 1):

From [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/he-or-she-versus-they):

> It’s often important to use language which implicitly or explicitly includes both men and women, making no distinction between the genders. This can be tricky when it comes to pronouns. In English, a person's gender is explicit in the third person singular pronouns (i.e., he, she, his, hers, etc.). There are no personal pronouns that can refer to someone (as opposed to something) without identifying whether that person is male or female. [...]
>
> In the past, people tended to use the pronouns **he, his, him, or himself** in situations like this:
>
> - A researcher has to be completely objective in *his* findings.
>
> Today, this approach is seen as outdated and sexist. There are other options which allow you to arrive at a ‘gender-neutral’ solution, as follows:
>
> You can use the wording **‘he or she’, ‘his or her’**, etc.:
>
> - A researcher has to be completely objective in *his or her* findings.
>
> This can work well, as long as you don’t have to keep repeating ‘he or she’, ‘his or her’, etc. throughout a piece of writing. [...]
>
> You can use the plural pronouns **‘they’, ‘them’, ‘their’** etc., despite the fact that, technically, they are referring back to a singular noun:
>
> - A researcher has to be completely objective in *their* findings.
>
> Some people object to the use of plural pronouns in this type of situation on the grounds that it’s ungrammatical. In fact, the use of plural pronouns to refer back to a singular subject isn’t new: it represents a revival of a practice dating from the 16th century. It’s increasingly common in current English and is now widely accepted both in speech and in writing.

In your case, I would say any of the following:

- It is really hard for someone who has no respect for *his or her* (or *her or his*) own values to be respected by others.
- It is really hard for someone who has no respect for *their* own values to be respected by others.

Comment: The grammar in the rest of the sentence needs correction as well: *"It is really hard **for** someone who has **no** respect **for** (their/his or her) own values to be respected by others."*